# Testing code in a Rails engine with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple but it's proven rather hard.

I want to write tests using RSpec for classes that I've put in the `lib` directory of a Rails Engine.

Here are exactly the steps I'm using:

```
rails plugin new mygem -T --mountable --full --dummy-path=spec/dummy
```

Then I `cd mygem; vim mygem.gemspec`

I add the following line to mygem.gemspec:

```
s.add_development_dependency "rspec-rails"
```

I run `bundle install; rails generate rspec:install`

Then I edit `~/mygem/lib/mygem/engine.rb` adding the following:

```
module Mygem
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Mygem

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec
    end
  end
end
```

I create a very simple class in the lib directory, `~/mygem/lib/mygem/something.rb`

and add the following:

```
module Mygem
  class Something
    def hi
      "hi"
    end
  end
end
```

Create a test file `~/mygem/spec/something_spec.rb`

then add the following:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Mygem::Something do
  it 'says hi' do
    s = Mygem::Something.new
    expect(s.hi).to eq('hi')
  end
end
```

And boom, I get the following output:

```
rspec
~/Documents/mygem/spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `require': cannot load such file -- ~/Documents/mygem/config/environment (LoadError)
  from ~/Documents/mygem/spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  from ~/Documents/mygem/spec/something_spec.rb:1:in `require'
  from ~/Documents/mygem/spec/something_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `load'  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `each'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1325:in `load_spec_files'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:88:in `run'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:41:in `invoke'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any tips as to what I may be doing incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

It looks like your rails_helper is looking for an environment.rb file to load, which doesn't exist in a Rails engine. It does, however, exist in your dummy app, which is what RSpec is run against.

Try adding this into the top of your rails_helper file:

```
require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb", __FILE__)
```

Comment: Different error now: `$ rspec
~/Documents/mygem/spec/something_spec.rb:3:in '<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Mygem::Something (NameError)
  from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.3.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1327:in 'load'`

Comment: My spec_helper file usually has a require 'gemname' for every gem I'm going to need to test with, e.g. one of the projects I've worked on has this underneath the File.expand_path: 
    require 'rspec'
    require 'faker'
    require 'active_record'
    require 'factory_girl'
    require 'pry'
    require 'database_cleaner'

Comment: I'm having this issue and the answer doesn't change the error.

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it working after the following steps (thanks ccai for the suggestion):

in rails_helper.rb:

```
# Comment this line:
# require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment.rb", __FILE__)
```

then in lib/mygem.rb

```
require "mygem/something"
```

Works!

Comment: if this works you should have clicked the "checkmark"